# Dozer mapping inner classes

Tags: java, dozer

I need to map class A into class C using dozer framework.

```
public class A {

private String fielda1;
private String fielda2;

public String getFielda1() {
    return fielda1;
}
public void setFielda1(String fielda1) {
    this.fielda1 = fielda1;
}
public String getFielda2() {
    return fielda2;
}
public void setFielda2(String fielda2) {
    this.fielda2 = fielda2;
}
}


public class B {
private List<C> cList;

public List<C> getcList() {
    return cList;
}
public void setcList(List<C> cList) {
    this.cList = cList;
}

public static class C {
    private String fieldc1;
    private String fieldc2;

    public String getFieldc1() {
        return fieldc1;
    }
    public void setFieldc1(String fieldc1) {
        this.fieldc1 = fieldc1;
    }
    public String getFieldc2() {
        return fieldc2;
    }
    public void setFieldc2(String fieldc2) {
        this.fieldc2 = fieldc2;
    }
}
}
```

XML mapping file:

```
<mapping wildcard="false" map-null="false" map-id="test">
    <class-a>test.A</class-a>
    <class-b>test.B.C</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>fielda1</a>
        <b>fieldc1</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>fielda1</a>
        <b>fieldc2</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

When i try to map these classes i got following exception:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.B.C
at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:88)
at org.dozer.util.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:33)
```

It seams that dozer is not capable to handle this situation and uses class B as a package name. This issue can be resolved using custom converters. I just want to know is there any trick that could be used to convert these classes using just XML configuration ?

Comment: in StackOverflow it is customary to upvote the answers that helped you the most. Additionally it is also customary to accept the answer that more comprehensively helped to solve your problem. You upvote an answer using the upper arrow to the left of the answer (the number of votes will increase by 1). You accept an answer by clicking the checkmark below the answer so it turns solid green.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `test.B$C` like in the following example:

```
<mapping wildcard="false" map-null="false" map-id="test">
    <class-a>test.A</class-a>
    <class-b>test.B$C</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>fielda1</a>
        <b>fieldc1</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>fielda2</a>
        <b>fieldc2</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Also note that I changed the second field from `fielda1` to `fielda2`, it appeared to be a typo in your example.

**Note:** Because you set `map-id="test"` you must include `mapId` when you call map, like in:

```
B.C destObject = mapper.map(a, B.C.class, "test");
```

---

I tested and this is working correctly:

**A.java**

```
package com.test;

public class A {

    private String fielda1;
    private String fielda2;

    public String getFielda1() {
        return fielda1;
    }

    public void setFielda1(String fielda1) {
        this.fielda1 = fielda1;
    }

    public String getFielda2() {
        return fielda2;
    }

    public void setFielda2(String fielda2) {
        this.fielda2 = fielda2;
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;

public class B {

    private List<C> cList;

    public List<C> getcList() {
        return cList;
    }

    public void setcList(List<C> cList) {
        this.cList = cList;
    }

    public static class C {

        private String fieldc1;
        private String fieldc2;

        public String getFieldc1() {
            return fieldc1;
        }

        public void setFieldc1(String fieldc1) {
            this.fieldc1 = fieldc1;
        }

        public String getFieldc2() {
            return fieldc2;
        }

        public void setFieldc2(String fieldc2) {
            this.fieldc2 = fieldc2;
        }
    }
}
```

**mapping.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

    <mapping wildcard="false" map-null="false" map-id="test">
        <class-a>com.test.A</class-a>
        <class-b>com.test.B$C</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>fielda1</a>
            <b>fieldc1</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>fielda1</a>
            <b>fieldc2</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>

</mappings>
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.Mapper;

public class Main5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>(1);
        mappingFiles.add("mapping.xml");

        Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFiles);

        A a = new A();
        a.setFielda1("fielda1Value");
        a.setFielda2("fielda2Value");

        B.C destObject = mapper.map(a, B.C.class, "test");

        System.out.println(destObject.getFieldc1());
        System.out.println(destObject.getFieldc2());
    }

}
```

This outputs in the console:

```
...
fielda1Value
fielda1Value
```

Comment: @dino.keco glad to help. please upvote and accept answer as per StackOverflow conventions. See my comment in your question above.

Comment: Jorge Ferreira  Can you please help me on this ?